# Why does NSDateFormatter return nil date for these 4 time zones?

Tags: objective-c, ios6, nsdate, nsdateformatter, julian-date

Try running this in iOS6 (haven't tested pre iOS6):

```
NSDateFormatter *julianDayDateFormatter = nil;
julianDayDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[julianDayDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"g"];

for (NSString *timeZone in [NSTimeZone knownTimeZoneNames]) {
    julianDayDateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName: timeZone];
    NSDate *date = [julianDayDateFormatter dateFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", 2475213]];
    if (date == nil)
        NSLog(@"timeZone = %@", timeZone);
}
```

and you get the following output:

```
America/Bahia
America/Campo_Grande
America/Cuiaba
America/Sao_Paulo
```

Can anyone explain why these four time zones behave like this with NSDateFormatter set to julian day numbers? All other time zones makes NSDateFormatter return actual NSDates.

Comment: This is a solid question, but the obvious Jon Skeet effect here is absolutely obnoxious.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: It's tricky. I'm always nervous about tweeting this sort of thing. It definitely distorts the votes - but I want to draw people's attention to something I think they'll find amusing. At least the votes for my answer are irrelevant in terms of rep...

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I have a *suspicion*. Only a suspicion, but a pretty strong one.

That value represents October 19th 2064. The Brazilian time zones observe daylight saving time *starting at local midnight* - that's when their clocks go forward, so midnight itself doesn't exist. October 19th is one of those transitions.

Here's some sample code using Noda Time, my .NET date/time API. It checks whether the start of the day in every time zone it knows about is actually midnight:

```
using System;
using NodaTime;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var localDate = new LocalDate(2064, 10, 19);
        var provider = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb;
        foreach (var id in provider.Ids)
        {
            var zone = provider[id];
            var startOfDay = zone.AtStartOfDay(localDate).LocalDateTime.TimeOfDay;
            if (startOfDay != LocalTime.Midnight)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(id);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That produces a very similar list:

```
America/Bahia
America/Campo_Grande
America/Cuiaba
America/Sao_Paulo
Brazil/East
```

I suspect Brazil/East may be an alias for America/Sao_Paolo, which is why it's not on your list.

Anyway, to get back to your Julian day issue - I suspect the formatter always wants to return an `NSDate *` which is at the local midnight. That doesn't *exist* for October 19th 2064 in those time zones... hence it returns nil. Personally I'd suggest it should return the 1am value instead, but hey...

Comment: Thanks. You brought me onto the right track. This definitely has to do with transitions to day light saving. For the record: iOS5 does not behave this way, it always returns an NSDate. I filled a bug with Apple.

Comment: @lpa: Out of interest, what value does it return for those time zones? If it returns a value with a local time of midnight, that's a bug in a different way?

Comment: "what value does it return for those time zones?" in iOS5?

Comment: @lpa: Yes, exactly. Local midnight doesn't exist on those dates - it would make sense to return 1am, as that's the start of the local day.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. iOS5.0 returns 1am except for Brazil which returns 12am. In iOS5.1 it returns 1am for all time zones.

Comment: *"I'd suggest it should return the 1am value instead"* – You can tell it to do so: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40320768/1187415.

Answer (score 16):

Credits to Jon Skeet for putting me on the right track. However, I just want to clarify his answer in an iOS context.

When you ask NSDateFormatter to convert a julian day number into an NSDate, you can only specify whole numbers  (usually you can specify a decimal part for the hours/minutes/secs of the day) in the string to be parsed.
Because Apple demarcates julian days at midnight (as opposed to noon in astronomy, read more here: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/#Date_Field_Symbol_Table) and some midnights simply doesn't exists (thanks for pointing that out @JonSkeet) NSDateFormatter identifies that that particular point in time doesn't exist in that time zone and returns nil.

For the record, iOS5 does not behave like this and I agree with Jon Skeet, that NSDateFormatter should return an NSDate adjusted for DST instead of nil, as that particular julian day in fact exists! I filed a bug with Apple.