# Why NSDateFormatter is returning null for a 19/10/2014 in a Brazilian time zone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

```
NSString *dateString = @"19/10/2014";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
NSDate *myDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

Why `myDate` is null for this specific date (19/10/2014)??

If i change the `dateString` to `@"25/10/2014"`, `dateFormatter` return the date correctly... What is wrong with my code?

*** This code returns null when my iPhone time zone is "Brasilia, Brasil". When my time zone is "Washington, D.C., EUA" for example, the code returns the correct date.

Comment: nothing wrong with the code, it fine.  put break point & check whats wrong.

Comment: Nothing wrong with what you posted- runs fine on my end. Do you have a strange locale set on your device that could be interfering with your formatter? Per Apple's docs: `"Note that although setting a format string (setDateFormat:) in principle specifies an exact format, in practice it may nevertheless also be overridden by a user’s preferences—see Data Formatting Guide for more details."`

Comment: @Stonz2 i updated the question, please read the (*)

Comment: And you're not specifying a time along with the date?

Comment: @pawan try the code with your device in "Brasilia, Brasil" timezone

Comment: I think i found the error. Here in Brazil, 19/10/2014 - 00:00 does not exists because of the daylight saving.

Comment: Yeah, I figured it might be a DST thing.  NSDateFormatter is a little flaky when parsing dates without associated times.

Comment: This bug is really interesting, why do you closed it?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

We can reproduce your problem by explicitly setting the time zone to “Brazil/East”:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {
        NSString *dateString = @"19/10/2014";
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"Brazil/East"];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
        NSDate *myDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
        NSLog(@"myDate = %@", myDate);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the output:

```
2014-06-06 14:22:28.254 commandLine[31169:303] myDate = (null)
```

Since you didn't give a time in your `dateString`, the system assumes midnight.  But **midnight on that date doesn't exist in the Brazilian time zone**.

[Brazil changes from BRT (daylight-saving time zone) to BRST (non-daylight-saving time zone) on October 19, 2014](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/brazil/brasilia), skipping directly from the last moment of “18/10/2014” to “19/10/2014 01:00:00”.

Since “19/10/2014 00:00:00” doesn't exist, `NSDateFormatter` returns `nil`.  I think this is bad behavior on the part of `NSDateFormatter`, but we have to deal with it.  `-[NSDateFormatter dateFromString:]` eventually calls [`CFDateFormatterGetAbsoluteTimeFromString`](http://opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-855.14/CFDateFormatter.c), which uses the [`udat_parseCalendar` function](http://icu.sourcearchive.com/documentation/4.2/udat_8h_f9346209f0e409b220484d36c3c149bc.html#f9346209f0e409b220484d36c3c149bc) from the [International Components for Unicode (icu) library](http://site.icu-project.org/) to parse the date.

You can work around the problem by making the parser use noon instead of midnight as the default time.  No time zones change to/from daylight saving time at noon.  Let's write a helper function that returns noon of some arbitrary date in a given time zone:

```
static NSDate *someDateWithNoonWithTimeZone(NSTimeZone *timeZone) {
    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    components.timeZone = timeZone;
    components.era = 1;
    components.year = 2001;
    components.month = 1;
    components.day = 1;
    components.hour = 12;
    components.minute = 0;
    components.second = 0;
    return [[NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar] dateFromComponents:components];
}
```

Then we set the date formatter's `defaultDate` to this noon date:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {
        NSString *dateString = @"19/10/2014";
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"Brazil/East"];
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"dd/MM/yyyy";
        dateFormatter.defaultDate = someDateWithNoonWithTimeZone(dateFormatter.timeZone);
        NSDate *myDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
        NSLog(@"myDate = %@", myDate);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And here's the output:

```
2014-06-06 14:52:31.939 commandLine[31982:303] myDate = 2014-10-19 14:00:00 +0000
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have just tested NSDateComponents with the date "19/10/2014 00:00" and it automatically returns a date "19/10/2014 01:00", because of the daylight-saving here in Brazil.

Answer (score 3):

Rob Mayoff gave an [excellent explanation and solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24089663/1187415) to this problem. As Rob
pointed out, midnight on 19/10/2014 doesn't exist in the Brazilian time zone.

Another possible solution is to tell the date formatter to be
"lenient". In that case it will return the first valid date on the
given day:

```
NSString *dateString = @"19/10/2014";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"America/Sao_Paulo"];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"dd/MM/yyyy";

dateFormatter.lenient = YES;

NSDate *myDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString: dateString];
NSLog(@"myDate = %@", myDate);
// myDate = 2014-10-19 03:00:00 +0000
```

The result is "2014-10-19 03:00:00 UTC" which is "2014-10-19 01:00:00 BRST", i.e. the first valid date on that day when daylight saving time
started.

Answer (score -1):

If your date you wish to format is a specific format that you want all devices in all regions to understand, you will need to set a locale on your date formatter.

Without doing so, the date formatter will default to the devices locale. This would mean that Brazil's date format is seemingly not dd/MM/yyyy

You can force your date formatter to use a specific locale like so:

```
[dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_GB"]];
```

Hope this helps

W