# Swift Dateformatting fails for just a specific day

Tags: ios, swift

Today a very weird bug (or so I believe) started occurring. Here is the piece of code:

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
let dateObj = dateFormatter.dateFromString(serviceDate)
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
let serviceDateBr = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(dateObj!)
```

Now comes the strange part. When I set serviceDate = "2016-10-15", for example, it works:

```
let serviceDate = "2016-10-15"
...
print("dateSQL: \(serviceDate), dateBR: \(serviceDateBr)")
--------
Answer = dateSQL: 2016-10-15, dateBR: 15/10/2016
```

On the other hand, when I just change serviceDate to "2016-10-16" it crashes. Not on day 17, 18 or any other. Just 16.

```
let serviceDate = "2016-10-16"
...
print("dateSQL: \(serviceDate), dateBR: \(serviceDateBr)")
--------
Answer = fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

I already know that this fatal error occurs when the first formatting fails, returns nil and then I try to force unwrap it on stringFromDate(). But I can't see why it fails in first place. Can anyone help me?

If it is relevant, I am using Xcode 7.3.1. This bug occurs on device and simulator.

Many thanks.

Comment: Thanks, buddy! Helped me a lot!

Comment: Compare http://stackoverflow.com/a/24089663/1187415 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/40284272/1187415 for possible solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you are living in Brasil.

On October 16, 2016 the daylight saving time changes and there is no 0:00.

Comment: Oh. My. God. And how can I fix it? My purpose is to exibit only the date.

Comment: I mean, is there a way to fix without appending a 0:00 to the date string? This question is for curiosity only

Comment: You could separate year, month and day with `componentsSeparatedByCharacter` and work with `NSCalendar` and date components. `NSCalendar` considers daylight saving time changes.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried on Xcode 7.3 and it seems work fine and the results

```
dateSQL: 2016-10-15, dateBR: 15/10/2016
```

cloud you provide more info?

Comment: Thanks for your attention, friend! But the bug occurs only during October 16th. 15 works fine.