# 1st april dates of 80s failed to parse in iOS 10.0

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter, foundation

I found that DateFormatter `date(from:)` method can't parse a couple of specific dates. Method returns `nil` for the 1st april of 1981-1984 years. Is it a bug of Foundation? What can we do to perform parsing of such dates?

Xcode 8.0, iOS SDK 10.0. Here is a screenshot of a short playground example:
[image: a screenshot of a short playground example]

Comment: Which time zone are you in? Did daylight saving time start at that day?

Comment: It's not a bug of Foundation. I can get the correct value for these dates. This seems an specific configuration that doesn't works (timezone, gregorian calendar...). I'm testing it from London.

Comment: No, Its not a bug of Foundation. try changing the Timezone and calendar. it should solve your issue.

Comment: @MartinR you are right. This day daylight saving time started those 4 years only. Timezone: Europe/Moscow. How can I parse such dates without changing calendar or timezone?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This problem occurs if *daylight saving time* starts exactly on
*midnight*, as it was the case in Moscow in the years 1981–1984 (see for example [Clock Changes in Moscow, Russia (Moskva)](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/russia/moscow)).

This was also observed in

- [Why does NSDateFormatter return nil date for these 4 time zones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12922645/why-does-nsdateformatter-return-nil-date-for-these-4-time-zones) and
- [Why NSDateFormatter is returning null for a 19/10/2014 in a Brazilian time zone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24088730/why-nsdateformatter-is-returning-null-for-a-19-10-2014-in-a-brazilian-time-zone)

For example, at midnight of April 1st 1984, the clocks were adjusted one hour forward, which means that the date "1984-04-01 00:00" 
does not exist in that timezone:

```
let dFmt = DateFormatter()
dFmt.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
dFmt.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "Europe/Moscow")
print(dFmt.date(from: "1984-04-01")) // nil
```

As a solution, you can tell the date formatter to be "lenient":

```
dFmt.isLenient = true
```

and then it will return the first valid date on that day:

```
dFmt.isLenient = true
if let date = dFmt.date(from: "1984-04-01") {
    dFmt.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    print(dFmt.string(from: date)) 
}
// 1984-04-01 01:00:00
```

[A different solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24089663/1187415)
was given by rob mayoff, which is to make the date formatter use *noon* instead of midnight as the
default date. Here is a translation of rob's code from Objective-C to Swift:

```
let noon = DateComponents(calendar: dFmt.calendar, timeZone: dFmt.timeZone,
               year: 2001, month: 1, day: 1, hour: 12, minute: 0, second: 0)
dFmt.defaultDate = noon.date
if let date = dFmt.date(from: "1984-04-01") {
    dFmt.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    print(dFmt.string(from: date)) 
}
// 1984-04-01 12:00:00
```

Comment: The defaultDate trick is good to know. (Voted) The docs on that property are pretty much worthless. How did you figure out what it does?

Comment: @DuncanC: Actually I *guessed* that the `isLenient` property (which is even less documented) helps here. The `defaultDate` solution is just a translation of the linked-to Objective-C code to Swift, that was figure out by Rob Mayoff.