# Swift date formatter returns null for some date strings

Tags: swift, dateformatter

I'm trying to format "2018-03-22" String to Date using date formatter, but the result is Null!
for previous and next dates of this date, formatter works fine!
here is my code snippet:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter();
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";
let targetDate = dateFormatter.date(from: "2018-03-22") //----> targetDate is NULL
```

Comment: Which timezone are you in? It could be the same problem as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40284272/1st-april-dates-of-80s-failed-to-parse-in-ios-10-0 if daylight saving time starts at midnight on that day.

Comment: @MartinR as you said it is related to my timezone, thank you :)

Comment: @ZRoyal you just need to set your date formatter calendar