# Wrong behavior with pt-BR DateFormatter Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, dateformatter

I have this method that parse a string Date:

```
  let dateFormatterGet = DateFormatter()
  let stringDate = "31/01/1965"
  dateFormatterGet.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
  dateFormatterGet.locale = Locale(identifier: "pt_BR")
  let birthDate = dateFormatterGet.date(from: stringDate)
  print(birthDate)
```

If Date is 31/01/1965 (January 31st), the birthDate is returning nil, but if i change the day for 30, all works fine. What is wrong here?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. I get reasonable results for both strings. I'm testing with Xcode 11GM2.

Comment: What timezone are you in? Where the clocks adjusted on that day? – Compare [1st april dates of 80s failed to parse in iOS 10.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40284272/1st-april-dates-of-80s-failed-to-parse-in-ios-10-0) for a similar issue and possible solutions.

Comment: @MartinR you are right. the problem is daylight saving time. If you wanna, you can answer and i mark as correct.

Comment: On January 31, 1965 the clocks were adjusted one hour forward in Brasil. – @RobNapier: You can reproduce the problem by setting `dateFormatterGet.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "America/Sao_Paulo")`

Comment: @JoãoPedroMorais you just need to set the date formatter calendar property to any Calendar  `dateFormatterGet.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)` https://stackoverflow.com/a/32408916/2303865