# iOS Dateformatter convert from string return nil

Tags: ios, swift, date, nsdateformatter, date-format

I have a question about dateFormatter convert string to date.
because I try to convert date string, and my function always return nil when I using `19590401`.
But When I using `19590402`, it seems work fine.
What's wrong about my code?
I can't fix this bug? 
Thanks.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let dateString: String = "19590401"
                
        let format: DateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        format.dateFormat = "yyyyMMdd"
        format.locale = Locale(identifier: "zh_TW")
        format.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC+8")
        
        if let date:Date = format.date(from: dateString) {
            print("aaa : \(date)")
        } else {
            print("aaa : nil") //Always return nil.
        }
        
    }

}
```

Comment: it returns "aaa : 1959-03-31 21:00:00 +0000" for me in simulator. Try to check it again

Comment: Can't reproduce. Note that you misspelled `UTC` as `UCT`.

Comment: Similar issue (with possible solutions) here: [1st april dates of 80s failed to parse in iOS 10.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40284272/1st-april-dates-of-80s-failed-to-parse-in-ios-10-0).

Answer (score 5):

In Taiwan daylight saving time changed on April, 1st 1959 at midnight so 00:00 didn't exist

https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/taiwan?year=1959

Comment: Thanks,it's awesome. Have any idea to fix it?

Comment: You could use a neutral locale like `en_US_POSIX`