# Swift 5 - Unexplainable DateFormatter Crash

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, dateformatter

My app uses a timer which is constructed using a string in the `MM-dd-yyyy h:mm a` format. When the user surpasses the time noted by the resetTimeString, the next reset time is determined by incrementing to the next day (the 'a' value doesn't change) and storing the value in the database. Simply put, it represents a daily timer and each user is able to choose their own 'a' value.

I had a number of users reach out concerning a crash and after comparing their values in the database, it appears they all had a `resetTimeString` of `03-14-2021 2:00 AM`

```
    var resetTime: Date?
    let resetTimeFormatter = DateFormatter()

    resetTimeFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy h:mm a"
    
    if let resetString = resetTimeString { //value in DB
        resetTime = resetTimeFormatter.date(from: resetString)! // <- Only crashes with 03-14-2021 2:00 AM 
    }
```

I tested a range of different values for the `resetTimeString` value, and they all work perfectly fine:

`03-13-2021 2:00 AM`

`03-14-2021 1:00 AM`

`03-14-2021 3:00 AM`

`03-15-2021 2:00 AM`

I am very confused about this crash and thought I would seek some assistance; **any help is appreciated**!

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24088730/1187415, https://stackoverflow.com/q/40284272/1187415.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your locale the daylight saving time changes at 2 am on March 14, 2021, therefore the particular date doesn't exist.

Comment: You're a lifesaver -  do you have any advice for resolving this?

Comment: You could ask `Calendar` to give you the next (valid) time after or before `03-14-2021 2:00 AM`

Comment: Are these dates actually local times to the machine that's decoding them? (It seems odd that you would have recorded a non-existent time.) I would assume they're actually UTC times or local to some other time zone. If so, then set the `timezone` property of the DateFormatter.

Comment: that is correct, the dates are local to the device

Comment: This is my first app on the app store and it's been an incredible learning experience, I appreciate your guys' input/wisdom!