# DateFormatter returning nil for valid Date in format "dd/MM/yyyy"

Tags: ios, swift, swift5, dateformatter

I'm using a DateFormatter to convert a String to Date, but when the String is "25/10/1986" or "25/10/1987" the result is nil.

Already removed the locale and timeZone, but the result is still nil.

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "pt_BR")
formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "BRT")
formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"

print(formatter.date(from: "25/10/1986"))
```

Comment: I copy/paste your code in Playground and couldn't reproduce.

Comment: This is reproducible for the Brazilian time zone "BRT", `TimeZone(abbreviation: "BRT")`

Comment: Add new Info, thanks guys.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24088730/why-nsdateformatter-is-returning-null-for-a-19-10-2014-in-a-brazilian-time-zone

Comment: One workaround is to use offset from GMT instead, `formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: -10800)`